# Javascript: Change background color of false answer radio button

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

```js
function radioResult(){
 var r = document.getElementsByName('0');
 for(var i = 0; i < r.length; i++){
  if(r[i].checked){
   rValue = r[i].value;
   if(rValue!='1') {
    r.style.backgroundColor='blue';
   } else {
    alert('correct');
   }
  }
 } 
 qNo++;
 aCount2++;
}
```

```html
<input type='radio' name='0' value='1'>a<br>
<input type='radio' name='0' value='2'>b<br>
<input type='radio' name='0' value='3'>c<br>
<input type='radio' name='0' value='4'>d<br>
<hr>
<button id="Mcqsbtn" onclick="radioResult()">Result</button>
```

I want the background of radion button change to blue if the answer is false. How to do it. 
http://jsfiddle.net/mhabib555/k3h9c046/

**Update**

Thank you guys . I solved it by your help

Comment: You can't change css properties of radio input elements so easy. Check this: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953 You will need labels, and few more things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you going to want to target the actual element i.e..

```
 r[i].style.backgroundColor='blue';
```

This will apply the property to your element but radio button are not designed to have a background color. I suggest you wrap each button in a div with some padding and style the div instead.

```js
function radioResult(){
 var r = document.getElementsByName('0');
 for(var i = 0; i < r.length; i++){
  if(r[i].checked){
   rValue = r[i].value;
   if(rValue!='1') {
    r[i].parentElement.style.backgroundColor='blue';
   } else {
    alert('correct');
   }
  }
 } 
 //qNo++;
 //aCount2++;
}
```

```css
.wrap{
  padding:5px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<input type='radio' name='0' value='1'>a<br>
 </div> <div class="wrap">
<input type='radio' name='0' value='2'>b<br>
   </div>   <div class="wrap">
<input type='radio' name='0' value='3'>c<br>
    </div>    <div class="wrap">
<input type='radio' name='0' value='4'>d<br>
 </div> 
<hr>
<button id="Mcqsbtn" onclick="radioResult()">Result</button>
```

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer

**Html**

```
<div><input type='radio' name='0' value='1'>a</div>
<div><input type='radio' name='0' value='2'>b</div>
<div><input type='radio' name='0' value='3'>c</div>
<div><input type='radio' name='0' value='4'>d</div>    
<hr>
<button id="Mcqsbtn" onclick="radioResult()">Result</button>
```

Javascript

```
function radioResult(){
    var r = document.getElementsByName('0');
    for(var i = 0; i < r.length; i++){        
        if(r[i].checked){
            rValue = r[i].value;
            if(rValue!='1') {
                r[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor='blue';
            } else {
                alert('correct');
            }
        }
    } 

}
```

Please refer [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sahilgupta202/x1sndehc/7/)

**Explaination**

You have to set the `background-color` of a particular radio button. So instead of `r.style.backgroundColor='blue'` you should use `r[i].style.backgroundColor='blue'`.

Answer (score 0):

Target the element as:

```
 r[i].parentElement.style.backgroundColor='YourColor';
```